# How can I add keycontrol with createjs? I want to slide the container and background with arrow keys

Tags: javascript, dom-events, createjs, easeljs

```
stage.addChild(background);
stage.addChild(container);
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);
function handleTick(event) {
   background.x-=1;
   container.x-=2;
   stage.update();
}
```

background and container contains large images more than the width of canvas so that it gives a parallax effect for the game.

Comment: you can add listener for the keypress event and compare key value with the arrow key values

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to move them with w a s d or arrow keys or whatever you want, there's this file I like to use. (I recommend saving it in another document)

```
var Key = {

    _pressed: {}, 
    preventedDefaults:[32, 37, 38, 39, 40, 16, 90, 81, 68, 83, 87, 65], 
    Z: 90,
    Q: 81,
    D: 68, 
    S: 83,
    W: 87,
    A: 65,
    SPACE: 32,
    LEFT: 37,
    UP : 38, 
    RIGHT: 39, 
    DOWN: 40, 
    SHIFT: 16,
    isDown: function(keyCode){
        return this._pressed[keyCode];
    },
    onKeyDown: function(e){
        this._pressed[e.keyCode] = true;


        if(this.preventedDefaults.indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },
    onKeyUp: function(e){
        delete this._pressed[e.keyCode];

    }
}

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){Key.onKeyUp(e);}, false);
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){Key.onKeyDown(e);}, false);
```

So as you can see the numbers in the array preventedDefaults are the numbers of the keys on your keyboard which you can look up on google if you need other key codes.
To use it, you do it with a simple if statement like so:

```
if(Key.isDown(Key.DOWN) || Key.isDown(Key.S)){
move down or whatever
};
```

(make an if statement for each direction you want to be able to go)
As you can see you can use multiple keys for the same movement , so you can use the arrow keys and w a s d for example.

I hope this was clear enough. If not, ask away.